# Communicating between cordova and a python server

Tags: javascript, python, api, cordova

I've been trying to make a cordova app get information from a python server. I am relatively new to JavaScript but I've been trying to connect using sockets, but I couldn't get them to communicate and I can't use API since cordova blocks cross domain APIs.
How can I get them to communicate?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!. it could be better if you add some snippet code thus the comunity will be able to help you. take a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First, run two servers in the same domain. And use proxy server.

Here's an example case.
If your major app is one of Python, set proxy as:

```
yourdomain.com/ -> Python server
yourdomain.com/elsewhere/ -> Cordova server
```

Or you could set cordova app as the major app.

Second, communicate between them via HTTP or socket. It also can be done sharing a temp file or database.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your API Server does not respond using CORS. If you can setup your python server to respond using CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). There would be no issues. If it will work with the chrome developer Console then it works with cordova.

If it you can not make that, I would suggest writing a Firebase Functions that becomes a man in the middle to the story.